# Запуск отдельной графической сессии на встроенной видеокарте в линукс

Tags: xorg

Нужно запускать второй граф. сеанс (plasma), параллельно с первым, таким образом, что-бы тот использовал интегрированную графику и не имел отношения к дискретной.

[xorg.conf](https://pastebin.pl/view/8f652968)